# Returning/Passing a reference as its protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, protocols

Given

```
@protocol Person<NSObject>

@interface Greek : NSObject <Person>
```

Can you define a method as

```
+(id<Person>)newGreek{
return [[Greek alloc] init];        
}
```

and use the return type as

```
id<Person> person = [Persons newGreek];
```

Or call a method

```
Greek *greek = [[Greek alloc] init];
[self talk:greek];
```

which is defined as

```
-(void)talk:(id<Person>)person
```

If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Have you tried any of these? That's probably the easiest way to answer "can you X" questions.

Comment: actually I have and surprised to realise you can't but coming from Java doesn't look right so maybe I'm missing something. Also I think it's good enough question to have on SO for reference along with any alternatives.

Comment: What is it you are expecting the code should do since you tested your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. In [Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html) in the *Objective-C Programming Language*, the section on Type Checking specifically shows the first form, and the second works as well, even though it is not listed on that page. The protocol declaration (`<Person>`) is a type modifier which can be used on any objective-c object, meaning you can use it wherever you define the type of the object.

Comment: It does show the "- (id <Formatting>)formattingService;" but not it's usage. That and the error message I get "initializing 'id<Person>' with an expression of incompatible type 'Greek *'" isn't reassuring. Same applies for the second scenario "sending 'Greek *' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<Person>'"

Comment: That warning means that it doesn't think `Greek*` and `id<Person>` are compatible. Is the header file for the Greek class imported in the file you are calling it from?

Comment: thanks @ughoavgfhw for walking through it and coming up with an explanation. Been bitten before by XCode's inability to provide a more detailed message on top of the compiler. That and the fact that I couldn't find a trivial example or pinpoint a single remark like yours made it even more mind boggling.

Comment: @Cue: details can be found in the Objective-C Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-TPXREF151">http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-TPXREF151